# GLSL branching behaviour

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a rather simple fragment shader with a branch and I'm a bit unsure how it is handled by the GLSL compiler and how it would affect performance.

```
uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform vec2 texSize;
uniform vec2 targetSize; 

void main()               
{                  
    vec4 color;
    if(texSize == targetSize)
        color = texture2DNearest(sampler, gl_TexCoord[0]);
    else
        color = texture2DBicubic(sampler, gl_TexCoord[0]);
    gl_FragColor = color;        
}
```

I have read from an [AMDs document](http://developer.amd.com/media/gpu_assets/04%20Clever%20Shader%20Tricks.pdf) that sometimes both branches are executed, which would not be a good idea in this case. Without further information nor access to disassembly I'm unsure what to think about this, and how to avoid it if it is a problem?

And also from my understanding a branch based on a uniform variable will not incur any significant overhead since it is constant over a single pass?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you have it:

```
il_ps_2_0
dcl_input_generic_interp(linear) v1
dcl_resource_id(0)_type(2d)_fmtx(float)_fmty(float)_fmtz(float)_fmtw(float)
eq r2.xy__, c1.xyyy, c0.xyyy
imul r5.x___, r2.x, r2.y
mov r1.x___, r5.x
if_logicalnz r1.x
    sample_resource(0)_sampler(0) r6, v1.xyyy
    mov r7, r6
else
    sample_resource(0)_sampler(0) r8, v1.xyyy
    mov r7, r8
endif
mov r9, r7
mov oC0, r9
endmain
```

To rephrase a bit what Kos said, what matters is to know if the guard condition can be known before execution. This is the case here since `c1` and `c0` registers are constant (constant registers start with letter `'c'`) and so is `r1.x` register value.

That means this value is the same for all invocated fragment shaders, therefore no thread divergence can happen.

Btw, I'm using [AMD GPU ShaderAnalyser](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-shaderanalyzergcn) for transforming GLSL into the IL.
You can also generate native GPU assembly code for a specific generation (ranging from HD29xx to HD58xx).This is really a good tool!

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 5):

Yes, IIRC you won't hit a performance overhead since all the threads in a single batch (warp) on a single GPU processor will go through a single branch. By 'thread' I mean 'a single execution line of the shader'.

The efficiency problem arises when a part of threads executed at the given time by a given processor *(which'd be up to like 32 threads AFAIK; depends on hardware, I'm giving the numbers for G80 architecture)* would branch into several branches - two different instructions at a time cannot be executed by one processor, so firstly the "if" branch would be executed by a part of threads (and the remaining would wait), and then the "else" branch would get executed by the rest.

That's not the case with your code, so I believe you're safe.