# GLSL branching cost on modern GPUs

Tags: opengl, optimization, glsl, shader, gpu

I read that branching on some GPUs is very inefficient, especially on old ones. However, I don't know the performance impact of code like this:

```
void main(){
    if (int(gl_FragCoord.x)%2==1){
         for (int i=0; i<256; i++){
              someCalcs();
         }
     }
}
```

When a GPU core finish its shader execution (probably because it didn't take the for), the core executes another fragment? the processor stalls until nearby fragment executions are completed?

Comment: AFAIK the way most modern GPUs work is by processing a block of pixels at the same time. If some fragments fail an `if` condition, then they have some flag set that causes no write operations to happen, so the entire block can still run the inside of the `if` statement. So if one fragment passes the condition, then effectively all of the fragments in the block have to run it. I may be wrong though; can someone else more knowledgeable confirm?

Comment: What you call a "GPU core" (and what GPU vendors market as such) is nothing more than an ALU. There is simple no own control flow per ALU. In this particular case, as fragment shader execution is always done in blocks, your non-uniform control flow virtually guaranetees that that `someCalcs` loop is executed for _every_ fragment that is generated.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I've also read that, but I also read that this was on old hardware. I don't have good information for modern GPUs.

Comment: @derhass Are you sure of that? Which is the size of these blocks? (I know this could vary between hardware vendors)

Comment: Could give some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299506/glsl-branching-behaviour

Comment: @dv1729: I think the typical number nowadays is 32 shader invocations in a block, making 128 ALUs. But in your case, that does not really matter. GPUs are basically reuired to execute 2x2 blocks of fragment shaders in parallel to be able to calculate the derivates. Your code guarantees divergent control flow in every single of such quad.