# Cost of Branching on uniforms on modern GPUs

Tags: opengl, glsl

When using GLSL on modern (GL3.3+) GPUs, what is the likely cost of branching on a uniform?

In my engine I'm getting to the point where I have a lot of shaders. And I have several different quality presets for a lot of those. As it stands, I'm using uniforms with if() in the shaders to choose different quality presets. I'm however worried that I might achieve better performance by recompiling the shaders and using #ifdef. The problem with that is the need to worry about tracking and resetting other uniforms when I recompile a shader.

Basically what I want to know is if my fears are unfounded. Is branching on a uniform cheap on modern GPUs? I have done a few tests myself and found very little difference either way, but I've only tested on an nVidia 680.

Comment: The driver is free to recompile the shader with inlined uniforms itself if it sees that the cost of branching otherwise would be too great.

Comment: Thread divergence, where parallel invocations of a shader take different control paths, is a major issue in modern GPUs. Uniforms are applied to all invocations in a program, however, so this is not an issue. Avoiding branching on vertex attributes or otherwise dynamic data is a better use of your time.

Comment: Ok, so in practice, it's unlikely on a modern GPU to be any slower than recompiling with constants, either because the branches are little different from those on a CPU, or because the compiler will just recompile the shader automatically. 

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Jagoly: Whether a driver compiles shaders multiple times to flatten branches is not something we as non-driver developers know. My intuition tells me this actually is not very common, the overhead of keeping one copy of a shader for every possible combination of branch conditions makes it impractical. Instead, subroutines were created in OpenGL to expose this sort of thing directly to the developer without any hidden driver magic behind the scenes.

Comment: I answered a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604221/how-to-make-glsl-shaders-modular-without-using-string-manipulation/20605122#20605122) a while ago. It looks like only using uniforms [can have issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29911554/1888983).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLSL branching behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299506/glsl-branching-behaviour)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will admit that I'm not an expert, but perhaps my speculation is better than nothing.

I would think that branching on uniforms is indeed fairly cheap. It's clearly much different from branching on texture or attribute data, since all the ALUs in the SIMD will follow the same code path from the shader, so it is a "real" branch rather than an execution mask. I'm not too sure how shader processors suffer from branch bubbles in their pipeline, but the pipeline is certainly bound to be more shallow than in general-purpose CPUs (particularly given the much lower clock-speeds they typically run at).

I wish I could be more helpful and I'd also appreciate if someone else can answer more authoritatively. I, for one, wouldn't worry too much about branching on uniforms, however. But as always, if you have the possibility, do profile your shader and see if it makes any noticeable difference.