# How to remove unused resources from an OpenGL program

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I am trying to create something like effect system for OpenGL, and I want to be able to define a number of shaders in the same file. But I discovered the following problem. Say I have two shaders: A and B. Shader A uses texA and shader B uses texB. Then despite the fact that neither shader A uses texB nor shader B uses texA, both textures will be enumerated in both programs (I am using separate programs, so every shader corresponds to one program). One consequence is that I cannot have many textures defined in one file since the shader will fail to link (it compiles successfully but the linker then complains that the number of texture samplers exceeds the HW limit). Other problem is that I am doing automatic resource binding and my shaders have lots of false resource dependencies.

So is there a way to tell the shader compiler/linker to remove all unused resources from the separate program?

Comment: So to clarify, you have some common code that defines a bunch of samplers and gets included in a number of shader programs. Even though most samplers aren't used in each program (so you'd think they could be compiled out) you still get errors about having too many defined?

Comment: @jozxyqk That's correct. In HLSL file, I can have as many textures or uniform buffers as I want. Only these textures (buffers) that are actually used by the shader are included in the shader. In GLSL, when I define a sampler or a uniform buffer in a file, all separate shader programs will list that resource in a program introspection.

Comment: You could use #idef to have texB only declared when in shader B for example.

Comment: Were you on an Intel HD4000 GPU? Pretty sure it's a driver bug where the driver doesn't kill dead sampler uniforms.

Answer (score 0):

Shader sampler units are not there to select textures, but to pass texture units to the shader. The textures themself are bound to the texture units. So the selection which texture to use should not be done in the shader, but in the host program.

Or you could use bindless textures if your OpenGL implementation (=GPU driver) supports these.

Comment: I am not very good at OpenGL terminology, which is sometimes very confusing to me. What I did was this experiment: I defined many texture samplers in one file (say, 64). Then I wrote a bunch of functions that access these samplers, BUT the functions are NEVER called by any shader in the file. So in fact no samplers are accessed in the shader at all. I was able to compile that shader successfully, but then I got this error:
`OPENGL DEBUG MESSAGE: GLSL link failed for program 2, "": Number of Fragment Texture Image Units exceeds HW limits.`

Comment: The other issue is that if a uniform buffer is defined in the file, then program introspection of _every_ program returns this buffer even when the shader does not access the buffer.

Comment: @Egor the sampler maps you a TIU (HW Texture image units). You're requesting too many in your shaders, when the architecture of your code should probably be that you only need ONE of these, and simply in your GL API calls just use TIU #0 with whichever texture goes with whichever shader. Everyone else has already explained as much so I don't really know why I'm writing this just using different words.